# Visual Studio warning D9025 for seemingly compatible options

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the error

```
D9025   overriding '/sdl-' with '/GS-'
```

`/sdl-` turns off the Security Development Lifecycle checks, and `/GS-` turns off stack overflow security checks. Seemingly these options should be compatible, but I still get the warning. How do I fix it?

And before anyone asks, yes, I need these options off since the security cookie shows up in profiling as expensive.

Comment: It is just a wonky message, /sdl overrides /gs-.  Since the default for /sdl is already /sdl-, you simply avoid the diagnostic by leaving the project setting at its default setting (blank).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation for `/sdl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) :

> /sdl enables a superset of the baseline security checks provided by
>   /GS and overrides /GS-. By default, /sdl is off. /sdl- disables the
>   additional security checks.

Since `/sdl` is a superset of `/GS` and `/sdl` is off by default but `/GS` isn't you get this Enterprise™ error message. Just only disable `/GS` explicitly.